# Como habilitar "Telephony Actions" no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Como "habilitar" *Telephony Actions* no *Android Device Monitor*? Pois gostaria de fazer teste de chamada no emulador mas o campo está desabilitado.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se ler a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html) referente ao DDMS verificará que é dito que a aba "Emulator Control" [não é mais suportada](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html#ops-location).

O suporte a essas funcionalidades passam a ser fornecidas directamente no [Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#extended)